# Polynomial - showing root is integer

Tags: polynomials

The question is: the polynomial $x^3 + ax^2 + bx + c = 0$ has root $\frac{p}{q}$.
If $a$, $b$ and $c$ are integers, show $\frac{p}{q}$ is  an integer.
I've had a go and used factor theorem but can't  seem to get anywhere.
Any help much appreciated! :)

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Rational_Root_Theorem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

we can take here $(p,q)=1$. Then 
 $$ c+b\frac{p}{q} + a\frac{p^{2}}{q^{2}}+ \frac{p^3}{q^3}=0$$
Multiply the above equation by $q^{2}$ to obtain
$$cq^{2}+bpq+ap^{2}=-\frac{p^{3}}{q}$$ Because $p$ and $q$ in $\mathbb{Z}$, it follows that $\frac{p^{3}}{q}\in \mathbb{Z}$, so $q$ must be $\pm 1$. Hence $\frac{p}{q}$ must be integer.

Answer (score 1):

More generally,

> If $r$ is a rational root of a monic polynomial with integer coefficients, then $r$ is an integer.

This is essentially the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem).

The key to the proof is taking $r=\frac{p}{q}$ in *lowest terms*.

Comment: What is the meaning of monic polynomial? Does it mean that leading coefficient is 1?

Comment: @JaideepKhare, yes, monic = leading coefficient is $1$.

Comment: I still don't know how to show it :/